# MongoDB Compass: How to generate "_id" for nested objects when inserting a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to insert some data into my MongoDB API using MongoDB Compass. My issue is that only the outer object gets an "_id" automatically generated. So the nested objects in posts ect have no "_id". Is it possible to have ids generate for all objects?

This is a demo version of the data I'm inserting:

```
{
    "company_name":"Company name",
    "columns":[
        {
            "name":"Opportunities",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Prospects",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0.25"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Proposals",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0.5"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"Presentations",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0.75"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        },
        {
        "name":"Won",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"1"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        },
        {
        "name":"Lost",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"1"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        },
        {
            "name":"No Opportunity",
            "percentage":{
                "$numberDecimal":"1"
            },
            "total":{
                "$numberDecimal":"0"
            }
        }
    ],
    "board_posts":[
        {
          "company_type": "Surveying",
          "lines_of_business": "Strategic Advisors",
          "author_id":
          {
            "$oid": "5ea02eaa1c9d440000911537"
          },
          "division": "Advisory"
        },
        {
          "company_type": "Damage Management",
          "lines_of_business": "Strategic Sales",
          "author_id":
          {
            "$oid": "5ea02eaa1c9d440000911537"
          },
          "division": "Advisory"
        },
        {
          "company_type": "Claims Management",
          "lines_of_business": "Strategic Sales",
          "author_id":
          {
            "$oid": "5ea02eaa1c9d440000911537"
          },
          "division": "Advisory"
        }
    ],
    "divisions":[
        {
            "name":"Advisory"
        },
        {
            "name":"M&A"
        },
        {
            "name":"Partnerships"
        }
    ]
}
```

An "_id" will be generated the outer object for example:

```
{
    "_id":{
        "$oid": "5ea02eaa1c9d440000919999"
    },
    "company_name":"Company name",
    "columns":[ objects ],
    "board_posts":[ objects ],
    "divisions":[ objects ]
}
```

But I want an _id to be generated for each object inside columns, board_posts, divisions as well.

Comment: Are you attempting to import documents via the Compass JSON import? If so, I don't think there is a way to specify a generated `ObjectId()` as valid JSON. Have you considered using a driver like python/pymongo where it is easy to specify.

Comment: Yeah I'm just inserting the JSON using the Compass JSON import. I'll have to look into drivers. Never used them before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible from MongoDB compass... I wasted quite a while finding a solution and end up writing a script to do the same.

here is the script gist

https://gist.github.com/bansalvks/c6b5b2bdddc18e0957e26434d165ca1d

Hope this will help coming visitors :)

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * 1-to-many of ObjectIDs from a MongoDB Compass export... 
 *
 * NOTE: This must be 1 line because _MONGOSH "reasons"
 * NOTE: This replaces INLINE (AKA better come correct!)
 *       Choose a different target in $set if you want
 *
 * COLLECTION = your target collection
 * columnWithIds = your array of foriegn keys field [$oid:ID] export
 *
 * MongoDB Compass=>_MONGOSH after importing field *as a string*:
 */
db.COLLECTION.find().forEach(doc=> { let columnWithIds = JSON.parse(doc.columnWithIds); db.COLLECTION.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { columnWithIds: columnWithIds.map(id => ObjectId(id.$oid)) }}, { upsert: true } ); })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There isn't anything to cite. I wrote it, it's plain javascript using MongoDB Compasses _MONGOSH command line.